# Neo4J - Extending Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking into developing Neo4J plugins/extensions; however, I would like to create functions that I could use in the browser (i.e. code my own `graph_size()` and use it in cypher with `return graph_size()`). Is anyone familiar with this and how could it be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

You could look into Unmanaged Extensions which are written in Java and can be exposed over the REST API interface. Details for these are [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).

Unfortunately, there is not yet any support for user-defined functions that can be accessed from within a Cypher query, though. These are on the roadmap but have no timescale attached at this stage.

Comment: Ok, let's say that I do use the plugin module and I use the terminal to get my results in json. Is there any way to get this json and put it in the browser API to visualize the graph?
Also, as a side question, can I get my results in any other format that json?  (-H "Content-Type: application/json").
Thank you.